# Expanding ISP Config 3 subdomain disk size on Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, subdomain, expand

I have ISP Config 3 Install on amazon and i just expanded the volume from 8gig to 30gig and when i ssh into the main ispconfig instance or any subdomain instances i get whats below. But when i try an add files or edit any of my sub domains i get "file system is full". How can i edit the subdomain settings so the subdomain knows it has enough space?

```
    /dev/xvda1             30G  6.2G   22G  22% /
udev                  821M  4.0K  821M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 332M  240K  332M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  829M     0  829M   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb             147G  188M  140G   1% /mnt
/dev/mapper/vgpool-data
                      3.0G  2.9G   28K 100% /mnt/data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wanted to know. I needed to expand my LVM /dev/mapper/vgpool-data

I checked lvdisplay and vgdisplay to make sure i had enough room to expand and ran resize2fs -p on it and it worked. I got this info from [here](http://www.tcpdump.com/kb/os/linux/lvm-resizing-guide/expand.html)